# Threejs camera-controls limit azimuth angle

Tags: three.js

I'm using `camera-controls`, a library based on `three-orbit-controls` to navigate around a threejs scene.

I made this function to move from one position (`checkpoint`) to the other, while looking at different positions (`lookatpoint`).

The library let's me orbit around those `lookatpoint`s as well, but for some of them I want to limit the angle of the horizontal rotation so that the camera does not intersect with other objects in the scene.

```
moveTo(checkpoint, lookat) {
  // reset rotation constraints
  if (this.azimuthAngleConstraint == true) {
    this.cameraControls.minAzimuthAngle = -Infinity;
    this.cameraControls.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity;
    this.azimuthAngleConstraint = false;
  }
  // look at "lookatpoint" from checkpoint
  this.cameraControls.setLookAt(
        checkpoint.x,
        this.PLAYER_HEIGHT,
        checkpoint.z,
        lookatpoint.x,
        this.PLAYER_HEIGHT,
        lookatpoint.z,
        true,
  );
  // set rotation constraints
  if (checkpoint == 'someCheckPoint') {
      this.azimuthAngleConstraint = true;
      this.cameraControls.minAzimuthAngle = -Math.PI / 2;
      this.cameraControls.maxAzimuthAngle = Math.PI / 2;
  }
}
```

When I try to orbit around a `lookatpoint` that has the rotation limit, the camera orbits around in the opposite direction.

I think this is the behavior that is [described in the documentation:](https://github.com/yomotsu/camera-controls#find-the-absolute-angle-to-shortest-azimuth-rotatation)

```
You may rotate 380deg but actually, you expect to rotate -20deg.  
To get the absolute angle, use the below:  

const TAU = Math.PI * 2;
function absoluteAngle( targetAngle, sourceAngle ){
  const angle = targetAngle - sourceAngle
  return THREE.MathUtils.euclideanModulo( angle + Math.PI, TAU ) - Math.PI;
}
```

I don't understand how to adapt this, I'm using `setLookAt` and not doing manual rotations.

Thank you for any suggestions